# shelljs execution gets stuck on DigitalOcean

Tags: r, node.js, digital-ocean, shelljs, seurat

I have a `React` web app hosted on `DigitalOcean` (`Ubuntu 16.04`). The app has an `R` script on the backend (`node`) that is invoked by `shelljs` (`shCMD` command invokes the `R` script. It never gets inside the exec callback):

```
exec_full_analysis = shell.exec(shCMD, function(code, stdout, stderr) {
 if (code === 0) {
      console.log('Program output:', stdout);

      pdfService.drawChartsPDF(typeArr, analysisId, datasetArr, pairArr, filterArr);

      console.log('sendStatus 200')

      res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
      console.log('Program stderr:', stderr);
      //res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  });
```

I am using `foreverjs` to start the server. It is running in a `conda` environment. So, when the script starts running initially I see correct log output (`R` script is running) that `foreverjs` provides me with but very quickly log output stops being produced. No errors neither in the browser, nor in the `forever` log output are present. The server gets to a certain stage in my `R` script and somehow gets stuck. Is there a way to figure out at all what is going wrong? What would you recommend? Locally everything is working just fine. The only thing that may be different is `conda` environment, but I would expect it giving an error but there is none.

> Update

I looked into `/var/log/syslog` but I see no `OOM` errors: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/python-script-gets-killed

> Update

It is not an issue with `foreverjs`: running simple `node server.js` stucks at the same place in `R` script.

The script gets stuck in `Seurat`- package function `ScaleData`:

```
 seurat_object <- ScaleData(object = seurat_object, vars.to.regress = c("nUMI"))
```

with the following output:

> ScaleData is running on non-normalized values. Recommended workflow is to run NormalizeData first.
>   Regressing out: nUMI
>     |                                                                      |   0%

But, of course, locally it is running well. And on the server it gets stuck on the second `for`-loop iteration, so one time it runs just fine on the server, but the second time it fails as if there is a restricted time for running a process set on `DigitalOcean`.

> Update

The server was `apache2`. I switched to `nginx` and now the server runs fine, it is not getting stuck and the issue is almost solved except that now I am getting `504` gateway timeout errors.

Answer (score 1):

So, I do not know why but it was `apache2` server problem. I switched to `nginx`, but then `RAM` out of memory errors appeared which I fixed by reducing the amount of memory my `R` script uses:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx6000m")
```

It was `-Xmx8000m`. Then the script was finishing correctly on the server, but on the client I saw `504` gateway timeout errors which I fixed by the solution I found here: https://asdqwe.net/blog/solutions-504-gateway-timeout-nginx/

Just created file at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf` with:

```
proxy_connect_timeout       3000;
proxy_send_timeout          3000;
proxy_read_timeout          3000;
send_timeout                3000;
```

After which it finally started working